# Converting Hbase program to runnable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, hbase

I wrote a simple java code which will list all the tables in Hbase. Its running fine on eclipse. But when I converted it to runnable jar and try running it, I am getting `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` exception.

Following is my java code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.*;


public class ListTables {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.flush();
        Configuration conf= HBaseConfiguration.create();
        Connection conn= ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
        Admin admin= conn.getAdmin();
        HTableDescriptor tableDes[]= admin.listTables();
        for(HTableDescriptor td : tableDes) {
            System.out.print(td.getNameAsString() + " : ");
            for(HColumnDescriptor cd : td.getColumnFamilies())
                System.out.print(cd.getNameAsString() + ", ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

And I am getting following exception while running the Jar after converting it into runnable jar

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.parseStaticMapping(Groups.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.UserProvider.<clinit>(UserProvider.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
    at ListTables.main(ListTables.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 1
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3116)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1885)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:49)
    ... 9 more
```

Can any one please tell what is the correct way of converting these kinda code to runnable Jar...

Answer (score 0):

Digging to the source code you can find that this condition in Shell class fails

```
  private static boolean IS_JAVA7_OR_ABOVE =
      System.getProperty("java.version").substring(0, 3).compareTo("1.7") >= 0;
```

Check your `java.version` system property, maybe set it in your code

Comment: i am using java 1.8

Comment: @Subhankar print System.getProperty("java.version") when your program starts

Comment: the print for System.getProperty("java.version") gave `1.8.0_45` as output when I ran on eclipse, but when I converted it into jar and ran on terminal, it gave the exception as mentioned question without printing any thing.

Comment: @Subhankar if you add println statement as a first line of your program it can't fail with exception, because hadoop classes initialization will happen later. you're doing something wrong

Comment: I have edited the java code in the question. I added the print statement in the first line itself. But still getting same exception.

Comment: @Subhankar does it print 1.8.0_45 when you run your jar?

Comment: No, it doesn't print when any thing when I run the jar. It directly gives exception. But it prints `1.8.0_45`,when I run it on eclipse.

Comment: Actually my system was having java 9. But eclipse was running java 8. When I changed my system's java to java 8, it started working fine. May be some problem in java 9.